# PHP cURL function for GET method

Tags: php, curl, get

I am trying to write a cURL function for GET method. Following is the code:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    $token="43e6c623dda8f35dXXXXec57d58e91154a";
    $code="13200XX";
    $url="https://test.delhivery.com/c/api/pin-codes/json/?token=".$token."&filter_codes=".$code;
    echo $url;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $return = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    echo $return;
```

When I *echo* the above `$url`, I am getting the desired output but where I am wrong to write a *cURL* function, because when I am placing the same URL token in the *cURL* function I am getting blank page.

Please help me.

Comment: what's the output of `echo curl_error($ch);` ?

Comment: page is blank. Even if i use echo curl_error($ch);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be plenty of reasons why it is not working.

Before doing all these steps below check if url in browser or postman or any other client returns correct response and also set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`

1. Check what's the output of `echo curl_error($ch);` if it's empty then go to next steps
2. Add browser header with `curl_setopt()`  `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` some servers maybe set to deny connection if there is no browser header
3. Accept cookies in curl with `curl_setop(`) `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`
4. This url is secure that is why you need either to add certifcate or set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST`options to 0